# Problems with second argument of simple `replace()`

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, replace, capturing-group

I don't understand, why doesn't this code work properly?

```
"a-b".replace(/-(\w)/g, p1 => p1.toUpperCase()); // "a-B", instead of "aB"
```

It has to be simplest solution for exchanging CSS's hyphen-syntax on camelCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(/-(\w)/g).exec("a-b")
// [ "-b", "b" ]
```

So, `"b"` is the second argument passed to the `replace` callback, the first argument is the whole match.

```
"a-b".replace(/-(\w)/g, (p1, p2) => p2.toUpperCase())
// "aB"
```

EDIT it would be more clear written this way:

```
"a-b".replace(/-(\w)/g, (match, p1) => p1.toUpperCase())
// "aB"
```

Comment: On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) I was told, that `p1`, `p2` … (in functions) are equal to `$1`, `$2` … (in strings).

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky the article you've linked to mentions that the first argument passed is the whole match, then `p1...pn` are parenhesized submatches. Sou youre right, but `p1` that would correspond with `$1` is the 2nd argument.

Comment: Yes, at the very last moment I've got it.